# For loop not returning back to the first forloop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, scope, copy

I am having issues with my script returning back to the first for loop in this program, right now it only returns to the second one. I am trying to figure out how to force it to through all the step.

Thanks in advance

```
import copy

test = {'AEP': {'days': [1]}, 'AES': {'days': [32]},'AIS': {'days': [7]},'TWO': {'days': [35]}}

print (test)
for stock in test:
    a = stock
    print ("step one")
    for stock in test.itervalues():
        print ("step two")
        for days in stock.itervalues():
            print ("step three")
            for i in days:
                print ("step four")
                if i <= 30:
                    days[days.index(i)] = i + 1
                else:
                    test_2 = copy.deepcopy(test)
                    test_2.pop(a)
                    print (str(a) + " Has been removed")
                    test = copy.deepcopy(test_2)

print (test)
```

Current flow/logs:

```
{'AEP': {'days': [1]}, 'AES': {'days': [32]}, 'TWO': {'days': [35]}, 'AIS': {'days': [7]}}
step one
step two
step three
step four
step two
step three
step four
AEP Has been removed
step two
step three
step four
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fortest.py", line 19, in <module>
    test_2.pop(a)
```

Here is what I would like to see as a end result

```
test = {'AEP': {'days': [1]},'AIS': {'days': [7]}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on yet, but what are you trying to do? Just filter out keys that contain a `dict` whose `'days'` key contains a list that contains a value greater than 30?

Comment: There are several issues with your current code, unfortunately. You could try to fix them all, but there's a better way to do this, if I'm understanding your goal. Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: This is part of a much larger script but here is the goal. I am trying to make it so when my stock sells, I do not purchase it for another 31 days. When the stock is purchased it is added as a nested dictionary with the value of 0. Each day the market opens it adds one and once it reaches 30, it will be removed from the do not buy dictionary.

Comment: But what I said is how you're filtering the `dict`, right?

Comment: @cyphase I was not finished the comment before you replied, but that is not how I want it to operate.

Comment: Let's take this one step at a time. Why do you have all the nested `dict`'s and `list`'s? Why not just `{'AEP': 1, 'AIS': 7}`?

Comment: @cyphase I agree that would be a good way, but I wanted to make it more scalable in case I had other criteria in the future. The reason I put the list in there is the nested dictionary kept returning it  as a tuple and I had trouble constantly changing it.

Comment: I highly recommend not adding complexity until you need it. It wouldn't be hard to add later, and until then, you don't need to deal with it. Plus there are better ways to do it, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and combined the first for loop with the second one so that the variable will still be the same one it reaches the if and else statements.

```
import copy

test = {'AEP': {'days': [1]}, 'AES': {'days': [32]},'AIS': {'days': [7]},'TWO': {'days': [35]}}


print (test)
for stock,stock_name in zip(test.itervalues(),test):
    a = stock_name
    print ('step one')
    for days in stock.itervalues():
        print ("step two")
        for i in days:
            print ("step three")
            if i <= 30:
                days[days.index(i)] = i + 1
            else:
                test_2 = copy.deepcopy(test)
                test_2.pop(a)
                print (str(a) + " Has been removed")
                test = copy.deepcopy(test_2)

print (test)
```

Current flow/logs:

```
{'AEP': {'days': [1]}, 'AES': {'days': [32]}, 'TWO': {'days': [35]}, 'AIS': {'days': [7]}}
step one
step two
step three
step one
step two
step three
AES Has been removed
step one
step two
step three
TWO Has been removed
step one
step two
step three
{'AEP': {'days': [2]}, 'AIS': {'days': [7]}}
```